# Problems creating first Zend Framework 2 project

Tags: frameworks, zend-framework2

ZF 2 is running on MAMP. At the moment I read "Pro Zend Framework Techniques: Build a Full CMS Project" by Forrest Lyman.

If I call the project in Firefox I get the ZF 2 Welcome Page. Forrest wrote:

> >
>   First you need to update application/configs/application.ini, adding the layout resource to the production section, as shown in Listing 2-7.

Listing 2-7. Adding the Layout Resource to application/configs/application.ini

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
<<

The module folder contains an Application folder. But there's no configs folder and no application.ini as well.

Do I have to create that?

Is there a difference between ZF1 and ZF2?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference between ZF 1 and ZF 2. That book was written using ZF1.8 I believe. So you will be best off using a version of ZF 1. If you use a version newer then about 1.10 there will be some areas where the original code for the book may not work as expected.

For the most part the code in that book is still very good and the information in the book is good although it would be better if you had a working knowledge of ZF 1 before trying the exercises. It is a more intermediate level book. Try [Zend Framework in Action](http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/) or at least [Rob Allen's tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) first.